# How to block windows hostednetwork?

Tags: firewall

Is it possible to block Windows hostednetwork on Juniper SSG5. We conducted an investigation and found out that some of our employees have secretly created a Wifi using the hostednetwork feature in Windows. It's used for surfing the internet and stuff like games without restrictions via their mobile. Someone has been able to hack a PC with a working wired/wireless LAN card (where they've removed all restrictions) and created a hotspot using the command "netsh wlan hostednetwork".

Is there any way to block this hostednetwork over the network firewall not with windows domain?

Comment: What's "windows hostednetwork"? You should track down and remove anyone hacking your network...

Comment: This sounds like a job for Windows AD and GPOs. That would be something that you need to ask about on [sf].

Comment: the PC is out of our control.. Its a personal use of an executive....

Comment: hosted network is like sharing internet between lan and wlan and broadcasting the wlan like a hotspot...

Comment: Allowing equipment not owned and controlled by the company to connect to the company network is a recipe for lawsuits, malware, etc. The company should have a rule against connecting anything not owned by the company to the company network.

Comment: my question is there any way to block this over the network firewall?..

Comment: The illicit traffic is probably not running through your firewall, so trying to block it on the firewall is pointless. You need to deal with the problem instead of your idea of a solution. This seems to be an example of a classic [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

That's a job for GPO: in *Local Computer Policy, Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, and Network Connections* set _Prohibit installation and configuration of Network Bridge on your DNS domain network' to enabled and *Prohibit use of Internet Connection Sharing on your DNS domain network* to enabled.

It may take a while for the GPO to catch, so you might want to reboot his machine.

On his switch port, set ACLs to filter all traffic not from or to his MAC or IP address.

I'd disable the port completely. Surely you've got policies against this.